# web scraping with R in country which twitter is blocked

Tags: r, text, twitter, web-scraping, text-mining

I am trying to extract some data with rtweet package in R. The problem is that twitter is blocked in Iran and I have to use a software to pass the filtering. Unfortunately, I am facing this error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Failed to connect to api.twitter.com port 443: Connection refused
```

I am following regular steps for creating a token:

```
create_token(
app = "#######",
consumer_key = "#########",
consumer_secret = "############",
access_token = "#############",
access_secret = "############")
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved the problem. Here we go: You should not use proxifiers! The best way is to use a VPN to change the whole path of internet on your system.